# Amazon S3 Cname Setup

Tags: amazon-s3, cname, bucket

I have created a bucket in Amazon S3 and pointed a cname to its endpoint.

**Cname** = Image.TigerSupplies.com

**Endpoint** = http://tigersupplies.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Both Point to the same IP Address.

But Images.Tigersupplies.com returns an error.

This must be on Amazons Part.

Comment: Apparently the Bucket Name needs to match the cname.

I have read somewhere on the Amazon AWS forums, that you could not include special characters including periods in a bucket name.

Interestingly enough, the cname still points to the other bucket (tigersupplies) and Amazon automatically redirects it to the bucket called images.tigersupplies.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the Bucket Name needs to match the `cname`.

I have read somewhere on the Amazon AWS forums, that you could not include special characters including periods in a bucket name.

Interestingly enough, the `cname` still points to the other bucket (tigersupplies) and Amazon automatically redirects it to the bucket called `images.tigersupplies.com`.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will notice that your problem has been solved and be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: When you created the CNAME pointing at `tigersupplies.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` all that does is tell browsers to get the ip of `tigersupplies.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` when visting `Image.TigerSupplies.com`. Odds are that all the ips for every endpoint in the same region is the same. Amazon uses the `host` header in the http request to work out which bucket to open. The `host` header just contains the domain name in your URL bar. In short its only the CNAME (`image.tigersupplies.com`) and bucket name that are used to work out which bucket, not where you point your CNAME at